# XLS VBA - Slight Errors with Outlook Calendar Timing

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

The PullAllMeetings function is designed to pull all meetings from a selection of coworker calendars and print all available meetings between the start and end date. It generates and list of all 30 minute slots between the dates and then removes them if one of the individuals has a conflict. There's also supplemental function that tries to solve for recurring meetings (weekly, fortnightly, or monthly).

Unfortunately, the function sometimes eliminates or fails to eliminate 30 slots before or after a meeting. This error likely occurs around the time comparison line / how VBA is interpreting the timing when comparing dates (potentially one could be +/-.001 because of some truncation). I tried to adjust for that but wasn't able to come to a working solution. Does anyone have any ideas that could solve this issue? Would really appreciate the help.

```
Sub PullAllMeetings()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim slotSize As Double
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objCalendar As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objRecurrence As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
    Dim objOccurrence As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objAppointments As Outlook.Items  ' added to pull recurring appointments
    Dim row As Long
    
    Range("F4:G10000").Clear
    Range("F4:F10000").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("G4:G10000").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    
    ' get date from cells
    startDate = Range("D4").Value
    endDate = Range("D5").Value
    emailRange = Range("C12:C26").Value
    
    slotSize = Range("D6").Value
    RecSwitch = Range("D7").Value
    
    ' set start and end times for  search
    startDate = DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate), Day(startDate))
    endDate = DateAdd("d", 1, DateSerial(Year(endDate), Month(endDate), Day(endDate)))
    freeTimes = createDateArray(startDate, endDate)

    For Each emailAddress In emailRange
        If Not IsEmpty(emailAddress) Then
            
            Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
            Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            
            ' added to pull recurring appointments
            Set recipient = objNamespace.CreateRecipient(emailAddress)
            Set objAppointments = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9).Items.Restrict("[Start] >= """ & startDate & """ and [Start] <= """ & endDate & """")
            objAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
            
            objAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
            Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & startDate & """ and [Start] <= """ & endDate & """ and [Duration] > 0")
            
            row = 1
            Do While TypeName(objAppointment) <> "Nothing"
        
                    If objAppointment.Duration <> 0 Then
                        
                        startTime = objAppointment.Start
                        endTime = DateAdd("n", objAppointment.Duration, objAppointment.Start)
                        
                        low = LBound(freeTimes)
                        high = UBound(freeTimes)
                        
                        i = low
                        
                        While i <= high
                            
                            'Start time of appointment is less than start time of slot. End time of appointment is greater than end time of slot
                            'Debug.Print startTime, endTime, freeTimes(i), DateAdd("n", slotSize, freeTimes(i)), startTime <= freeTimes(i), endTime > freeTimes(i)
                            If startTime <= freeTimes(i) And endTime - 0.001 > freeTimes(i) Then
                                DeleteFromArrayAtIndex freeTimes, i
                                i = 0
                                high = high - 1
                            'Start time of appointment is less than end time of slot. End time of appointment is greater than end time of slot
                            ElseIf startTime + 0.001 < DateAdd("n", slotSize, freeTimes(i)) And endTime >= DateAdd("n", slotSize, freeTimes(i)) Then
                                DeleteFromArrayAtIndex freeTimes, i
                                i = 0
                                high = high - 1
                            End If
                            
                            i = i + 1
                        Wend
                        
                        row = row + 1
                        Set objAppointment = objAppointments.FindNext
                        
                    End If
            Loop
            
            Set objOutlook = Nothing
            Set objNamespace = Nothing
            Set objCalendar = Nothing
            Set objAppointment = Nothing
            Set objRecurrence = Nothing
            Set objOccurrence = Nothing
            Set objAppointments = Nothing
            
        End If
    Next
    
    LastDate = DateAdd("d", -1, freeTimes(0))
    Max = UBound(freeTimes)
    offsetCount = 0
    For slotCount = 0 To Max
        
        If slotSize > 30 Then
            For x = 0 To (slotSize / 30) - 1
                If slotCount + x < Max Then
                    If freeTimes(slotCount) - freeTimes(slotCount + x) = 30 Then
                        slotCount = slotCount + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        
        Range("G4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Font.Bold = False
        If DateSerial(Year(LastDate), Month(LastDate), Day(LastDate)) <> DateSerial(Year(freeTimes(slotCount)), Month(freeTimes(slotCount)), Day(freeTimes(slotCount))) Then
            offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
            Range("G4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = DateSerial(Year(freeTimes(slotCount)), Month(freeTimes(slotCount)), Day(freeTimes(slotCount)))
            Range("G4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).NumberFormat = "dddd, mmm-d, yyyy"
            Range("G4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Font.Bold = True
            offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
            LastDate = DateSerial(Year(freeTimes(slotCount)), Month(freeTimes(slotCount)), Day(freeTimes(slotCount)))
        End If
        
        If RecSwitch Then
            W = IsTimeAvailable(freeTimes(slotCount), freeTimes, startDate, endDate)
            If W Then Range("F4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = "W"
            f = IsTimeAvailableFortnightly(freeTimes(slotCount), freeTimes, startDate, endDate)
            If W Then abc = ", F" Else abc = "F"
            If f Then Range("F4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = Range("F4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value & abc
            M = NextSameWeekdayAndWeek(freeTimes(slotCount), freeTimes)
            If W Or f Then abc = ", M" Else abc = "M"
            If M Then Range("F4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = Range("F4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value & abc
        End If
        
        Range("G4").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value = Format(freeTimes(slotCount), "h:mm AM/PM") & " – " & Format(DateAdd("n", slotSize, freeTimes(slotCount)), "h:mm AM/PM")
        'Range("D1").Offset(offsetCount, 0).NumberFormat = "h:mm am/pm"
        offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
        
    Next slotCount
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Function createDateArray(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Variant
    
    Dim dateArray() As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentDate As Date
    sTime = Range("D8").Value & ":00:00"
    eTime = Range("D9").Value & ":00:00"
    
    mEndDate = DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(endDate), Month(endDate), Day(endDate)))
    
    currentDate = startDate
    i = 0
    
    Do Until currentDate > mEndDate
        
        If Weekday(currentDate, vbMonday) > 5 Then GoTo ContinueDo
        
        
        For currentTime = TimeValue(sTime) To TimeValue(eTime) Step 30 / (24 * 60)
            ReDim Preserve dateArray(i)
            dateArray(i) = currentDate + currentTime
            i = i + 1
        Next currentTime
        
ContinueDo:
        currentDate = currentDate + 1
    Loop
    
    createDateArray = dateArray
    
End Function

Sub DeleteFromArrayAtIndex(arr As Variant, index)
    Dim myInt As Long
    If mIndex >= LBound(arr) And index <= UBound(arr) Then
        ' Shift elements to the left
        For myInt = index To UBound(arr) - 1
            arr(myInt) = arr(myInt + 1)
        Next myInt
        ' Resize the array
        ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1)
    End If
End Sub


'Recurring check

Function NextSameWeekdayAndWeek(inputDate, datesArray As Variant)
    Dim inputWeekNum As Integer
    Dim inputWeekday As Integer
    
    inputWeekday = Weekday(inputDate)
    x = GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek(inputDate)
    inputWeekNum = x

    For i = 0 To UBound(datesArray)
        If GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek(datesArray(i)) = inputWeekNum And Weekday(datesArray(i)) = inputWeekday And Format(datesArray(i), "hh:mm") = Format(inputDate, "hh:mm") And datesArray(i) > inputDate Then
            'Debug.Print datesArray(i)
            NextSameWeekdayAndWeek = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    NextSameWeekdayAndWeek = False
    
End Function

Function GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek(dt) As Integer

    Dim lngDayOfMonth As Long
    Dim lngWeekDay As Long
    Dim dtFirstDayOfMonth As Date
    Dim lngFactor As Long

    lngDayOfMonth = Day(dt)
    lngWeekDay = Weekday(dt, vbSunday) '<~~ Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc
    
    'does month start on Sunday?
    dtFirstDayOfMonth = DateValue("01-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Year(dt))
    If Weekday(dtFirstDayOfMonth, vbSunday) = 1 Then
        lngFactor = 1
    Else
        lngFactor = 2
    End If
    
    'get calendar week number for date
    GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek = Int((lngDayOfMonth - lngWeekDay) / 7) + lngFactor

End Function

Function IsTimeAvailable(inputDate, dateArray As Variant, sDate, eDate) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inputDay As Integer
    Dim inputTime As Double
    
    IsTimeAvailable = False
    inputDay = Weekday(inputDate) 'determine the day of the week of the input date
    inputTime = TimeValue(inputDate) 'determine the time of the input date
    
    DCount = -1
    tCount = -1
    
    LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, sDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ldate = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, sDate), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    dayDiff3 = Abs(DateDiff("d", eDate, dateArray(UBound(dateArray))))
    If dayDiff3 > 7 Then
        IsTimeAvailable = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For i = LBound(dateArray) To UBound(dateArray)
        
        dayDiff2 = Abs(DateDiff("d", dateArray(i), LastDate))
        If dayDiff2 > 7 Then
            IsTimeAvailable = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        If Weekday(dateArray(i)) = inputDay Then
            If LastDate <> Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
                DCount = DCount + 1
            End If
            If TimeValue(dateArray(i)) = inputTime Then
                tCount = tCount + 1
            End If
            LastDate = Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
        
        ldate = Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        
    Next i
    
    If DCount = tCount And DCount > 0 Then IsTimeAvailable = True
    
End Function

Function IsTimeAvailableFortnightly(inputDate, dateArray As Variant, sDate, eDate) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inputDay As Integer
    Dim inputTime As Double
    Dim dayDiff As Integer
    
    IsTimeAvailableFortnightly = False
    inputDay = Weekday(inputDate) 'determine the day of the week of the input date
    inputTime = TimeValue(inputDate) 'determine the time of the input date
    
    DCount = -1
    tCount = -1
    LastDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, dateArray(0)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ldate = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, dateArray(0)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    dayDiff3 = Abs(DateDiff("d", eDate, dateArray(UBound(dateArray))))
    If dayDiff3 > 14 Then
        IsTimeAvailableFortnightly = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For i = LBound(dateArray) To UBound(dateArray)
    
        dayDiff = Abs(DateDiff("d", inputDate, dateArray(i)))
        dayDiff2 = Abs(DateDiff("d", dateArray(i), LastDate))
        
        If dayDiff2 > 14 Then
            IsTimeAvailableFortnightly = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        If Weekday(dateArray(i)) = inputDay And dayDiff Mod 14 = 0 Then
            If LastDate <> Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
                DCount = DCount + 1
            End If
            If TimeValue(dateArray(i)) = inputTime Then
                tCount = tCount + 1
            End If
            LastDate = Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
        ldate = Format(dateArray(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    Next i
    
    If DCount = tCount And DCount > 0 Then IsTimeAvailableFortnightly = True
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds. If you specify seconds in the date-time comparison string, the filter will not operate as expected.

Although dates and times are typically stored with a date format, filters using the Jet and DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax require that the date-time value to be converted to a string representation. In Jet syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in either double quotes or single quotes. In DASL syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in single quotes.

To make sure that the date-time comparison string is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function available in VBA as shown below:

```
Set objAppointment = objAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & '" _ 
         & Format(startDate, "General Date") & "'")
```